# What happens to argument in alias after using it once?

Tags: bash, shell, alias

Why does this only print `arg` out once?

```
$ alias test="echo $1 $1 $1"
$ test arg
arg
```

This is on GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List aliases with `alias` command after you defined that alias and you will clearly understand it:

```
alias test="echo $1 $1 $1"
alias
```

Output:

```
alias test='echo   '
```

It simply expands to a string with variables only which were defined at execution time.
So this for example works (Vvariable MY_VAR is defined):

```
MY_VAR="foo"
alias test="echo $MY_VAR $MY_VAR $MY_VAR"
alias
```

Output:

```
alias test='echo  foo foo foo'
```

You can replace it with function

```
function test() {
    echo $1 $1 $1
}
```

Comment: Variables can be expanded at run time if aliases are defined with single quotes `alias est='echo 1${1} var${var}'`. The problem then is `$1` is still not populated as the OP expects. The function is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if `alias` supports $1,$2,... Its help keeps silence on that.

So I think that your command `test arg` is expanded like `echo $1 $1 $1 arg`. Where $1 is empty and you get your result.

1 more example:

```
$ alias test='echo $1 $1 $1'
$ test arg1 arg2
arg1 arg2
```

In the above example the alias `test=...` get's executed  and the net effect is we're let with an alias to the command `echo`. We can see this effect when we run the command `test arg1 arg2`. All we're doing is running `echo` and passing it the strings `arg1` and `arg2`.

```
$ echo arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Your example doesn't show anything other than "echo $1 $1  $1" is aliased as `test=echo`. And you're `test arg1 arg2` is really doing `echo arg1 arg2`.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm saying. Why minus?

Comment: It's not showing anything. The $1's are meaning less in an alias. I'm not sure what you're trying to say in your answer, it's reading a bit fractured to me. Keep word smithing it and I'll gladly undo it.

Comment: You say my post would be better without that example?

Comment: Yeah that example isn't helping your answer that much. If you leave it I'd add a couple of sentences explaining it a bit. Not trying to nit pick just trying to help you.

Comment: Something like what I wrote, sorry I didn't mean to beat you up about it, I was just trying to help you flesh out your idea better. I appreciate you sticking with it!

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Any way, I think, dsumsky's answer covers the same while it is more detailed and concise.

Comment: Yeah but this is a good first attempt, keep up the good work!